# Select a child td of a tr by id in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table from which, through jQuery, I want to select the text of firstname from the tr whose button was pressed.

A tr row look like :

```
....
<tr id = "2">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td id = "firstname">
        John
    </td>
    <td id = "lastname">
         Doe
    </td>
    <td>
            <button id = "2" class="button">change</button>
    </td>
</tr>
....
```

That button above is linked to a jQuery :

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var id = element.attr("id");
    var newusername = $("tr#"+id+" > td#firstname").html();
    alert(newusername);
});
```

Why doesn't my selector work?

Comment: What is `$(".change")`? Do you mean `$(".button")`?

Comment: Oops! I corrected it.

Comment: IDs need to be unique (only one); I suspect you are duplicating firstname in each row.  Change it to a class and change the lookup appropriately.

Comment: You can't have both `<tr id="2">` and `<button id="2">`. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: Is the button always in the same row as the name you want to select? Get rid of the ID on the button and use `$(this).closest("tr").find(".firstname")`.

Comment: @rfornal Thanks. It worked.  But why doesn't it work with id? Ids can be used multiple times, i guess.

Comment: No, they can't. We've said that several times, and in most of the answers.

Comment: Thanks. I should check the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since IDs must be unique, try ...

```
<tr id = "2">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </td>
  <td class = "firstname">
    John
  </td>
  <td class = "lastname">
     Doe
  </td>
  <td>
     <button data-id = "2" class="button">change</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

... and ...

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  var element = $(this);
  var id = element.data("id");
  var newusername = $("#" + id + " > .firstname").html();
  alert(newusername);
});
```

Changing the name IDs to classes and changing the selection should work.  Also, only one ID of 2.  I used `data-id` on the button so that I can still select what the value is and didn't duplicate the `id`.

**NOTE:**

The `data-` "data dash" attribute is an attribute that I used here to allow for quicker capture of the attribute; jQuery has a `.data()` function that specifically looks for these types of attributes.

**[.data() link](https://api.jquery.com/data/)**

Comment: That's not valid HTML markup as IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: Right ... changed it.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: It would probably be better to use `data-id` on the button. You should use a real ID for elements that you select by ID.

Comment: @Barmar; your probably right; it could go either direction.  I'll make that shift since it does then wrap with the ID.  Thanks.

Comment: @SumitSinha `data-id` is an interesting one ... `data-` as part of the element is "made up", but can be selected using the jQuery function `.data()` ... the function is what you should look for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have several element with the same id. In that case, the correct usage is to use a class:

```
<td class="firstname">
...
<td class = "lastname">
```

Then your selector becomes: `$("tr#"+id+" > td.firstname")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though people are suggesting to use `data-id` in this case.